# What do monopoles have to do with strong coupling?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, magnetic-monopoles, duality, instantons, solitons

My understanding is that strong coupling effects arise from instantons in the path integral.

But I sometimes read that monopoles (see the electric-magnetic duality) can allow one to calculate strong coupling effects. How do I reconcile this with my understanding that instantons are responsible for strong coupling effects?

Comment: A good starting point is these notes by 't Hooft:  [hep-th/0010225](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0010225)  However, be warned that there are some typos in the math.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is: Instantons mediate (in time) between configurations of different winding number. This can be thought of as the creation or destruction of monopoles, since monopoles carry winding number.

Therefore, in a QFT of monopoles, where monopoles can be created and destroyed, instantons will naturally be accounted for, providing the non-perturbative physics.

Comment: Actually I'm not satisfied with this answer for the following reason: the winding that the monopole carries (see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/744511/what-does-the-dual-gauge-field-have-to-do-with-topology?noredirect=1&lq=1) for instance) is not the same as the winding of the vacua between which the instanton mediates -- for instance, the monopole configuration carries a magnetic field while the vacuum obviously doesn't. So it is still not clear how a QFT of monopoles accounts for the instantons which are supposed to provide the non-perturbative physics.