# What does the dual gauge field have to do with topology?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, topology, duality

The dual gauge field, $V$, is defined by $$^{\star}F(V)=F(A),$$ where $F$ is the field strength. The 't Hooft operator $\exp(i\int_C V)$ creates the trajectory of a magnetic particle along $C$. But I don't really understand what this has to do with topology? There are two topological quantities that I am aware of:

- The topological number of a four-dimensional configuration which is a pure gauge at infinity ($S^3_{\infty}$) is $$\int d^4x\,\operatorname{tr}(F \tilde F).$$
- The winding number of a gauge transformation $\Omega(\mathbf x)$ is
  $$\int d^3x\,\epsilon^{ijk}\operatorname{tr}(\Omega^{-1}\partial_i \Omega~ \Omega^{-1}\partial_j \Omega ~\Omega^{-1}\partial_k \Omega).$$

However, neither of these allows me to compute the topological charge of a magnetic particle. So my question is: **How can I conclude that the magnetic particle is a topological excitation?**

Comment: $\tilde{F}$ is the dual of $F$

Comment: Everything has to do with topology but the fun begins when you find combinations whose information about geometry cancels out.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what this question is asking but https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/319419/50583 and its linked questions might help.

Comment: @dennis can you be more explicit about your doubt and provide a couple of references? (links, books, papers that you are consulting). Do you want to know how the 't Hooft operator works that way and what is it for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%27t_Hooft_loop

Comment: After the question edit, this may help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148588/226902. See this for the "dual" of the vector potential https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/647435/226902 (or this for the field strength https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/210282/226902)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 't Hooft operator creates a magnetic field which is a delta function smeared along the curve $C$. In this question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/745811/magnetic-field-due-to-singular-gauge-transformation/745912?noredirect=1#comment1671101_745912)
it was shown that a gauge transformation which is singular (i.e. multivalued) on a curve $C$ produces a magnetic field that is a delta function smeared along $C$. Therefore, the effect of the 't Hooft operator is to act with a singular gauge transformation of this kind.

But such gauge transformations are classified by $\mathbb Z^{N-1}$ ($N$ being the number of colors), which counts the winding of the $(N-1)$ $U(1)$'s of the Cartan subgroup around the curve $C$. So such a singular gauge transformation is said to create a magnetic monopole with charge $m\in\mathbb Z^{N-1}$.